# Proactive Dialog Bot Framework - Cannot continue the waterfall Dialog

Tags: .net-core, botframework, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

**Here I am trying to invoke a dialog and push it on the existing dialog stack, idea is to proactively call a Dialog and continue the waterfall structure of the dialog.**

Issue : I can start the dialog, and prompt user with Hero card to select Yes or No choices
but the Answer given by user does not stay in the same Dialog context.

Error : *Failed to continue dialog. A dialog with continueConversationDialog id could not be found.*

Below is the sample code snippet used for invoking the Dialog from controller

```
public class ProactiveMessageController : Controller
{
 private readonly BotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
 private readonly ConversationState _conversationState;
 private readonly IBot _bot;
 private readonly BotSettings _settings;
 private readonly ILastMessageSent _lastmessagesent;
 private readonly ContinueConversationDialog _dialog;

 public ProactiveMessageController (BotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, ConversationState conversationState, IBot bot, BotSettings settings, ILastMessageSent lastmessagesent, ContinueConversationDialog dialog)
    {
     _adapter = adapter;
     _conversationState = conversationState;
     _bot = bot;
     _settings = settings;
     _dialog = dialog;
    }

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
 try
  {
   await _adapter.ContinueConversationAsync(
   _settings.MicrosoftAppId,
   item.conversationReference,
   async (ITurnContext TurnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
      {
        var conversationStateAccessors = _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState));
        var dialogSet = new DialogSet(conversationStateAccessors);
        dialogSet.Add(_dialog);
        var dialogContext = await dialogSet.CreateContextAsync(TurnContext, cancellationToken);
        await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(_dialog.Id);
        await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(TurnContext,false,cancellationToken);
      },
        default(CancellationToken)
         );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
      }
}
```

Sample waterfall Dialog code snippet, is as follows

```
public class ContinueConversationDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        private readonly BotServices _services;
        private readonly LocaleTemplateManager _templateManager;
        private readonly IStatePropertyAccessor<UserProfileState> _accessor;
        private readonly IUserManagement _userManagement;

        public ContinueConversationDialog(
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IUserManagement userManagement)
            : base(nameof(ContinueConversationDialog))
        {
            _templateManager = serviceProvider.GetService<LocaleTemplateManager>();

            var userState = serviceProvider.GetService<UserState>();
            _accessor = userState.CreateProperty<UserProfileState>(nameof(UserProfileState));
            _services = serviceProvider.GetService<BotServices>();

            var ContinueConversation = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                PromptToContinueConversation,
                FinishDialogAsync,
            };

            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(ContinueConversation), ContinueConversation));
            AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(nameof(ConfirmPrompt)));
            _userManagement = userManagement;
        }

        public async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptToContinueConversation(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await sc.PromptAsync(nameof(ConfirmPrompt), new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = _templateManager.GenerateActivityForLocale("ConfirmPrompt"),
                RetryPrompt = _templateManager.GenerateActivityForLocale("InvalidOptionPrompt"),
                Style = ListStyle.HeroCard
            }, cancellationToken);    
            
        }

        public async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinishDialogAsync(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
                bool ContinueConversationresponse = (bool)sc.Result;

                if (ContinueConversationresponse)
                {
                //Continue the conversation on main dialog
                Console.Write("Selected Yes");
                return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Ask for feedback and close the conversation
                    return null;
                }
        }
    }
```

Part 1 where user is prompted with chocie works well, dialog is invoked without any issue
But when user submits the response I am not able to get it in same context.
I apply debugger and breakpoints in dialog to confirm the flow reaching the second step but it never does.

Can you please suggest how can we continue the conversation in same context after dialog is pushed on the current stack.

FYI:  I am saving the current dialog state as well but no luck continuing; Dialog classes are registered as Transient, I have tried making it Singleton but does not make a differnce.

Comment: Hey Rishabh, thanks for reaching out. Are you able to share the repository of this bot to reproduce this issue and debug your code?

Comment: I am also struggling with this. check my question for inspiration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894797/bot-framework-v4-node-js-how-to-go-to-next-waterfall-step-based-on-external-tri